# vnc to a docker container in vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, vnc

We run selenium driver tests on a docker host which is maintained via vagrant.
We get the error "Display :1 not found".
Now we want to actually try to see what is going on when we start the tests, so we want to remote desktop onto the docker container in the vagrant machine.

The machine is with centos 7, we use vagrand 1.9 with centos as vm-system and then we have the docker containers in there.

Does someone have any idea how to do that?